# ImportError: No module named api - WHat does it mean, and how to solve it?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, google-cloud-messaging

```
  File "/home/elias/git/pds/pds/RSASignApp/models.py", line 6, in <module>     
    from gcm.models import Device   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gcm/models.py", line 5, in <module>    
    from gcm.api import send_gcm_message
ImportError: No module named api
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite literal :) You have tried to import `send_gcm_message` from the `api` module or package by doing:

```
from gcm.api import send_gcm_message
```

Python has found the gcm package, and within the package structure it has looked for `api` and not found it, which is why it has raised that error. To solve it you would need to work out why the code is calling that import statement when the package doesn't have the required modules.

Was it [this package?](https://github.com/bogdal/django-gcm). If you go into the gcm package in that github repository you can see there is an api module present with a `send_gcm_message` function in it. Make sure you have the correct library installed, and the correct version of that library for what you're trying to do, you may have wanted [django-gcm](https://github.com/bogdal/django-gcm) and installed [python-gcm](https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm) by mistake